# Using Jersey For Gathering Information from RESTful API

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to get information from a REST API in a Java program.  It was recommended to me that I should use Jersey to do this.

From what I have read so far, Jersey seems to have two functions.  The first is to create a REST API and the other is to gather information from a REST API.  I am using an already created REST API, so I do not need the first function.

So I am looking for examples on how to do a simple GET request using Jersey.  However, every example I have found so far seems to be how to create your API to use GET or have been using a different version of Jersey (I am using Jersey with Glassfish).  I am struggling finding any information how to do this.

I have been using the following:  https://jersey.java.net/download.html.

And I have been trying to follow the following documentation (User Guide):  https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e1290

I would just like to know how to do a GET request using Jersey.  Any information on this or links to documentation / examples would be great.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build a REST *client*, not a REST *service*.
And you're in the right documentation, but the wrong chapter. What you're looking for is 5.3 [Overview of the Client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e2562).
Basically, you will use four pieces.

1. Client
2. WebTarget
3. Invocation.Builder
4. Response

A complete code example is in section 5.3.6.
To start, ignore the ClientConfig. Instantiate the simplest client using `Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();` and then focus on setting up your WebTarget and Invocation.Builder.